# R - use file path information to label data

Tags: r

I'm setting up an experiment and the software saves the raw data for every participant and related trial in this format:

`participant_0\Trial1\Trial1_001_midi_20161028_152703.csv.aborted
participant_0\Trial2\Trial2_001_midi_20161028_152813.csv.aborted
...
participant_1\Trial1\...
participant_1\Trial2\...`

Is it possible to take the data from the file path and add it as a column to my data frame so that all the data from e.g `Trial1_001_midi_20161028_152703.csv.aborted` contains a column with the participant ID and the trial?

`> head(Trial1)
  X start_time_seconds end_time_seconds pitch velocity
1 0           12.23170         12.23270    42      127
2 1           16.11092         16.11192    42      127
3 2           20.09615         20.09715    42      127
4 3           24.11638         24.11738    42       88
5 4           28.10661         28.10761    42      120
6 5           30.08972         30.09072    42      116`

I want to add a column for participant and trial with all 1's in this example

Comment: What is your expected output?  You can check `?basename`

Comment: As far as I see, it's a combination of `list.files()`, `substr()` and `cbind()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. You set up a function to import a single file, as well as adding a column with the file name. Then run that function across the list of files.

```
path–"~/Desktop/ut"
library( readr )
files <- list.files( path = path, pattern = ".csv", full.names = T )

# set up a function to read a file and add a column for filename
import <- function( file ) {
    df <- read_csv( file, col_names = F )
    df$file <- file
    return( df )
}

# run that function across all files.
library( plyr )
data <- ldply( .data = files, .fun = import )
```

I've run this on two basic example csv files I created, and the output looks like this:

```
> data

X1 X2 X3      file
1  a  6  5 ~/Desktop/ut/file1.csv
2  b  1  9 ~/Desktop/ut/file1.csv
3  c  3  1 ~/Desktop/ut/file2.csv
4  d  3  2 ~/Desktop/ut/file2.csv
```

You can then manipulate that column any way you need. In your example, the dataframe probably resembles the following:

```
data$file <- c( rep( "participant_0\\Trial1\\Trial1_001_midi_20161028_152703.csv.aborted", 2 ),
            rep( "participant_0\\Trial2\\Trial2_001_midi_20161028_152813.csv.aborted", 2 ) )
```

Get the parts you want using `strsplit`. For example:

```
data$participant <- sapply( sapply( data$file, strsplit, split = '[\\]' ), "[", 1 )

data$trial <- sapply( sapply( data$file, strsplit, split = "[\\]" ), "[", 2 )
```

Comment: My problem is that the file name does not hold that much relevant data. Rather I want to extract data from the file path and attach it to the file at the end of this path. So in  `participant_0\Trial2\Trial2_001_midi_20161028_152813.csv.aborted`  I would like to take  `participant` and `Trial2` and these as columns to the data from the .csv file

Comment: I've just adjusted the `list.files` call to give a full path instead of just a file name. From there, it's just a matter of `substring`-ing the `data$file` column the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `list.files()` to obtain your list programmatically; something like

```
fils <- list.files(recursive=TRUE)
```

(if your `getwd()` is where you want to start searching from.)

Assuming:

```
fils <- c("participant_0\\Trial1\\Trial1_001_midi_20161028_152703.csv.aborted",
          "participant_0\\Trial2\\Trial2_001_midi_20161028_152813.csv.aborted")
```

then:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

map(fils, function(x) {

  # read in your data, perhaps like this
  df <- read.csv(x)

  stri_split_regex(fils[1], "[\\._\\\\]")[[1]][-c(1,2,3,9,10)] %>% 
    setNames(c("trial", "field2", "field3", "date", "field5")) %>% 
    as.list() -> fields

  cbind(df, fields)  

})
```

That gets you a list of data frames.

The regex I used splits on dots, backslashes and underscores, providing a wealth of fields to add. I added them all since I had no idea which one was the participant id (but I suspect it's `field5`).

I also didn't know if you needed factors or not by default (this is trial data so you may be reading data assuming strings are factors). As a result, I included no code to keep strings as strings.

You can also use `map_df()` to make one big data frame out of all your files this way. Just substitute it for the `map()` call.

You should follow @rosscova's example/advice and avoid the anonymous function if you can. For me, this is one-off code. I suspect you'll have use of this again and may want to consider building a personal package of functions to use like this.